# Delete wp users based on role and registration date

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have about 180000 users in my wp_users database. Most of them are old and dormant. I fear this is slowing down my site (is this likely?). I want to safely delete old accounts along with all their associated data.

Using bulk delete plugins does not work as they timeout with so many users. I want to do it with mysql instead. By searching around I have found the following code:

```
DELETE 
    wp_users, 
    wp_usermeta 
FROM 
    wp_users 
    INNER JOIN wp_usermeta ON wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id 
WHERE 
    meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' AND 
    meta_value LIKE '%subscriber%' AND 
    user_registered < NOW() - INTERVAL 360 DAY
```

The code works but is it safe and is it the best way? Will it delete their associated meta data etc.

Comment: @George        Your query will delete much more than DORMANT users.  Anyone who REGISTERED more than 360 days AGO would be gone.  Is that really your goal?

Comment: Thanks Wilson, I'm actually going to set it to 720 days and run the script every year. This will apply to subscribers (non paying accounts) only. Anyone who has paid to use our service has the role of customer. The website is a revision site for people taking an exam (a 2 year course) when they are 16 so they would not need their account after two years. I'll put it in the t&c's.

Answer (score 3):

**Please first take a backup of your database before running this query**

Yes You can use this query to delete the user & user_meta data but if your theme/plugin saving users data in some others table(if you are using any plugin that store user data in other table) than you have to look again in database and modify your query according to this..

Comment: I'm revisiting this. Can you recommend the best way to safely delete a user from all tables? I only want to delete uses that are more than two years old and that don't have an active woocommerce subscription